# Why does error occurs when importing from same *sub*directory?

Tags: python, import

Consider this folder structure:

```
main.py
module_a/
    aa.py
    bb.py
    __init__.py
```

In `main.py`, I import aa as:

```
from module_a import aa
aa.yyy()
```

Then in `aa.py`, I import bb and include its functions as:

```
import bb
bb.xxx()
```

However, when I run `main.py`, python says "No module named 'bb'".

May I know why this happens. What is the correct way to import bb.

Thanks!!!

I have tried to write `aa.py` as:

```
import .bb
bb.xxx()
```

But it still does not work.

Comment: Actually `import aa` should not work from `main.py` either. If it does, your `sys.path` was polluted somehow. It should be `from module_a import aa` and `from module_a import bb`.

Comment: My fault. I have changed the code block. Sorry about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose the same file structure as stated in OP, and:

`main.py`:

```py
import module_a.aa

module_a.aa.thisFile()
module_a.aa.module_a.bb.thisFile()
```

`aa.py`:

```py
import module_a.bb

def thisFile():
    print("aa")
```

`bb.py`:

```py
def thisFile():
    print("bb")
```

Then, this will print

```
aa
bb
```

like you would expect. The main difference here, is that `bb.py` is imported in `aa.py` via `module_a.bb`. Running `main.py` gives no problem, however, running `aa.py` does not work in this way. That is why you might want to add folders to your path, such that you can call a function from a different file without this trouble. This is done via:

```py
import os, inspect, sys 

current_folder = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())))
parent_folder = os.path.dirname(current_folder)
sys.path.insert(0,parent_folder)
```

Then you can import your files such as `import file`. If you consider this option, I would suggest to do some reading about how this works. Tip: make sure you avoid cyclic import problems.

Answer (score 0):

> why this happens

Because the `aa` folder is not a place that Python is searching for modules.

Python's `import`s are absolute by default. They only look in specific places determined by `sys.path`. In `main.py`, `import module_a.aa` works because *the root folder of the project* happens to be on the `sys.path`; that folder contains a `module_a` folder; and that folder contains `aa.py`.

> What is the correct way to import bb.

**Please use relative imports** between files in your package. In this case, the necessary import in `aa.py` looks like:

```
from . import bb
```

Absolute imports are error-prone; a project that uses two packages whose contents have overlapping names will run into namespace collisions. (Sadly, the standard library uses absolute imports in most places, such that projects need to ban certain module names for safety.) Relative imports will also require much less maintenance, should you later rename a sub-package.

The only thing relative imports require is that the package gets loaded, which typically will happen automatically with the first (yes, absolute) import of any of the package contents. When the package is loaded, it automatically sets a `__package__` attribute on the modules in that package, which Python can use to resolve the relative imports. It's important to note that relative imports are relative to the **package hierarchy, not the directory structure**, which is why this is necessary; imports like `from .. import example` **do not** work by figuring out the current file location and then going up a level in the directory hierarchy. Instead, they check the `__package__` to figure out what the containing package is, then check the file/folder location for **that**, and work from there.

If the "driver" script is within the package, run it as a module, using the `-m` switch for Python. For example, from the root folder, if `module_a/aa.py` is the driver, use `python -m module_a.aa`. This instructs Python that `module_a` is the containing package for `aa.py`, and ensures it gets loaded even though no `import` in the code has loaded it.

Contrary to what many people will wrongly tell you, it is **almost never** required to manipulate `sys.path`; there are popular Python projects on GitHub, running hundreds of thousands of lines of code, which either do not use it at all or use it only once in an ancillary role (perhaps because of a special requirement for a documentation tool). Just don't do it.

Also contrary to what many people will wrongly tell you, `__init__.py` files are **not required** to create packages in Python. They are simply a place where additional code can be placed for package initialization - for example, to create aliases for sub-package contents, or to limit what will be imported with a `*`-import (by setting `__all__`).

> `import .bb`

This is just invalid. Relative imports **only** use the `from` syntax. See above for the correct syntax.